# Flask WTForm Validating on submit but not updating database

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I tried to insert data into database but it validates but does not commit. I have written similar codes for other forms but this one not working

**Form:**

```
    class ScheduleInterviewForm(FlaskForm):
        recruit = StringField('Recruit ID', validators=[DataRequired()])
        interviewdate = StringField('Interview Date', validators=[DataRequired()])
        starttime = StringField('Interview Time', validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Schedule Interview')
```

**Modal:**

```
    class ScheduledInterview(db.Model, UserMixin):
        __tablename__ = "scheduledinterview"
        interviewid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        interviewdate = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
        recruitid = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
        starttime = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
        status = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, default='N/A')
        reject_reason = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False,default='N/A')
```

**View:**

```
    @app.route("/ScheduleInterview", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def ScheduleInterviewPage():
        form = ScheduleInterviewForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            inter = ScheduledInterview(interviewdate=form.interviewdate.data,
                                       recruitid=form.recruit.data,
                                       starttime=form.starttime.data)
            db.session.add(inter)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Schedule has been submitted', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        rlist = DriverRecruit.query.filter_by(recruit_approve='yes', recruit_interview='pending')
        return render_template('ScheduleInterview.html', title='Interview', rlist=rlist, form=form)
```

**HTML Page:**

```
    
              {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
              
                
                  
                    
                      {{ form.recruit.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                      {{ form.recruit(class="form-control form-control-lg",value= m.recruitid,disabled=True) }}
                    
                      
                      {{ form.interviewdate.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                      {{ form.interviewdate(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                    
                  
                  
                    
                    {{ form.starttime.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.starttime(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                  
                  
    
                
              
              
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-success") }}
                Cancel
```

Comment: You're not passing all the required data, that is you have set your columns to `nullable=False` but your not including e.g. `starttime` or `reject_reason` when adding a new record.

Comment: But I have  default='N/A'   in the db.Model